# Printing stacktrace with boost library in MVSC 32 bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-stacktrace

Im trying to implement a solution in which the stacktrace is printed when an exception occurs. Im doing this in Qt creator and I need this to work with MingGW and MSVC compilers for 32 and 64 bits.

I tested boost library and i found this solution :
boost::stacktrace::to_string(boost::stacktrace::stacktrace());

This gives exactly what I need. The only problem is that this works for every compiler (MINGW 32 and 64 bits and MSVC 64 bits) but doesnt work for MSVC 32 bits, specifically in release mode. For this platform the stacktrace is empty and I cant find any similar case that can guide me with this problem.

Can someone give me some clue of where the problem could be? Is this a boost bug?

Edit:
Im running this from Qt Creator. This is the flags in the makekile.release file

DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG
CFLAGS        = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -O2 -Zi -MD -W3 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 /Fdrelease\pruebastack4.vc.pdb $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:__cplusplus -O2 -Zi -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fdrelease\pruebastack4.vc.pdb $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I..\pruebastack4 -I. -I../src -Iz:\zlib\common\src -Iz:\zlib\devices\src -IZ:\boost\boost_1_82_0 -I........\Qt\Qt5.12.11\5.12.11\msvc2017_64\include -I........\Qt\Qt5.12.11\5.12.11\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I........\Qt\Qt5.12.11\5.12.11\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc
LINKER        = link
LFLAGS        = /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'"

Thanks

I tried printing the stacktrace for every compiler and platform in Qt creator and works fine for all of them except MVSC 32 bits release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some test applicaiton:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

int nested_func(int c)
{
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
    return c + 1;
}

int func(int b)
{
    return nested_func(b + 1);
}
 
int main()
{
    func(777);
}
```

Now to make it work it have to be build with proper flags (copy paste from developer console):

```cpp
C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\stackTraceTest>cl main.cpp /std:c++20 /EHsc /Zi /Od /I F:\repos\component\Shared\ThirdParty\boost /D BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_WINDBG
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.34.31933 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.34.31933.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
/debug
main.obj

C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\stackTraceTest>main.exe
 0# boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> >::init at F:\repos\component\Shared\ThirdParty\boost\boost\stacktrace\stacktrace.hpp:77
 1# boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> >::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> > at F:\repos\component\Shared\ThirdParty\boost\boost\stacktrace\stacktrace.hpp:130
 2# nested_func at C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:6
 3# func at C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:13
 4# main at C:\Users\marekR22\Downloads\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:18
 5# __scrt_common_main_seh at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
 6# BaseThreadInitThunk in KERNEL32
 7# RtlUserThreadStart in ntdll
```

Note that flag `/Zi` is needed to properly print line numbers and function names.

Remember also that optimizations can inline some functions.

Comment: Is that example built in 32 bits release mode? I see /debug. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I test this for x64 (happily I did this month ago and just copy paste results here), but when you start developer console to use 32 bits it should just work the same way.

Comment: Thats the weird issue. If i run it in 64 bits release mode works just fine. But the stacktrace size is 0 for 32 bits... I am just clueless.

Comment: I've just rerun this test on my machine for Win32 and outcome is exactly same. Just extra one frame at bottom: `8# RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath in ntdll`

Comment: I cant find what the problem is, maybe is something related with Qt creator... Thanks anyways. I will continue searching

Comment: You should describe in question your build process - compiler flags.